# How to save path of drawn line in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made a screen where the user can draw around an image using image_painter and it works fine. Now I want to be able to save the path of the line the user drew but no matter how much I search I find nothing.

How could I do it? I also tried to add gestures but that didn't work. It seems very weird to me how such a library doesnt have the option to save the path

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_painter/image_painter.dart';

class DrawingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawingScreenState createState() => _DrawingScreenState();
}

class _DrawingScreenState extends State<DrawingScreen> {
  final _imageKey = GlobalKey<ImagePainterState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 600,
                child: ImagePainter.network(
                  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ-MhSib_BLGD1SYgEQpXUmmQy0TfyJjEbfDA",
                  key: _imageKey,
                  colors: const [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
                  scalable: true,
                  initialPaintMode: PaintMode.freeStyle,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Save or process the user's drawing here
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 12,
                    ),
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

flow this example.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_painter/image_painter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DrawingScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class DrawingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawingScreenState createState() => _DrawingScreenState();
}

class _DrawingScreenState extends State<DrawingScreen> {
  final _imageKey = GlobalKey<ImagePainterState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 600,
                child: ImagePainter.network(
                  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ-MhSib_BLGD1SYgEQpXUmmQy0TfyJjEbfDA",
                  key: _imageKey,
                  colors: const [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
                  scalable: true,
                  initialPaintMode: PaintMode.freeStyle,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Uint8List? byteArray =
                    await _imageKey.currentState?.exportImage();

                    if (byteArray != null) {
                      final result =
                      await imagegallerysaver.savefile(byteArray);
                    }
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 12,
                    ),
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**New changes added how to save file**

Comment: This is not exactly what I want, this solution basically gives me the image alongside the user's drawing, I want to somehow save the path of the drawing (coords, offsets or whatever)

Comment: try this 
image_gallery_saver: ^2.0.3

final result = await imagegallerysaver.savefile(byteArray);